# LDAP Query string size

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I was wondering if anybody knows if there are limitations on the size of an LDAP query.

I have an application that is enumerating `AD` via group membership. Using the query 
`(&(objectclass=group)(CN=Groupname*))` with Attribute of Member only pulls back the `DN` of the users where the application requires `SamAccountName`.

So. I have reversed the query and have searched for users that are `MemberOf`:

`(&(objectclass=user)(| (Memberof=CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,
DC=Domain,DC=nonprod)(MemberOf=CN=APP_TH_Admin_DEV,OU=Groups,OU=User Groups,DC=Domain,DC=nonprod)))`

This works in pulling back all members of each group

However, this statement does not...

`(&(objectclass=user)(| (MemberOf=CN=APP_TH_ContentStudio_DEV,OU=Groups,OU=User Groups,DC=domain,DC=nonprod(MemberOf=CN=APP_TH_Admin_DEV,OU=Groups,OU=User Groups,DC=domain,DC=nonprod)))`

The only thing I can think of is the size of the query?

Also, if anyone knows a way that you can pull back the `SamAccountName` from groups that would be even better :)

Comment: The filter you give in the second example is not a valid filter. Quality APIs and servers should reject that filter.

Comment: Now the third, not second.

Answer (score 1):

Terey is, of course correct.

Try:

```
(&(objectclass=user)(|(MemberOf=CN=APP_TH_ContentStudio_DEV,OU=Groups,OU=User Groups,DC=domain,DC=nonprod)(MemberOf=CN=APP_TH_Admin_DEV,OU=Groups,OU=User Groups,DC=domain,DC=nonprod)))
```

-jim

Answer (score 0):

You can export samaccountnames at least with this way (joeware adfind.exe):
adfind -default -f name=herewillbeyourgroup member -list | adfind samaccountname -list

Probably this does not solve your issue if you wish to query with single ldap search from the application itself.